# HD Audio 44.1 SPDIF

Tags: audio, codec

It has been known that integrated audio codecs (on board) CAN'T natively play 44.1 sample rate via analog jacks. But whether they also can't do it via digital toss-link output? resample occurs in this case too?

Comment: Hi. Please, add more tags so people can find your question: language, whatever the technology, etc

Comment: @eduyayo i cant add tag( spdif, 44.1khz, etc..